# AD connect problem (Device join type problem)

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have a problem with correctly configuring Azure AD sync, I hope you can advise me with it.

I have a AD on prem which is connected to Azure AD with Azure AD connect. When I join a new device to a domain, I use "join to local azure domain" option.  Everything works great, I am able to join device to the domain and I can also see it in my Azure AD under devices, however all my device are "Azure AD registered".

My understanding is that devices synced from AD sync should come up as "hybrid AD joined".

Why is AD sync not syncing my devices correctly? Where can I start trouble shooting this ?

I only have a single forest domain and separate AD sync server.

Answer (score 0):

How do you check they are not Hybrid joined. You may take a look at this
https://oofhours.com/2020/05/23/digging-into-hybrid-azure-ad-join/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have bumped into this article before but now I will get deeper into it.

Comment: I am checking in Azure Active Directory admin center. Under all devices Join type for all of them is "Azure AD registered". On top of it all devices have owners. My guess is something is wrong with SCP configuration, what else could it be ?